Describe the ring formed from $\mathbb{Z}$ by adjoining $a$ such that.....
Artin 11.5.4) c)
Describe the ring formed from $\mathbb{Z}$ by adjoining $a$ such that $a^3+a^2+1=0 , a^2+a = 0$
Is the following solution correct?
Given:
$$ R' = \mathbb{Z}[a] / (a^3 + a^2 + 1, a^2 + a) $$
Simplify the ideal $I$:
$$ I = (a^3 + a^2 + 1, a^2 + a) $$
$$ I = (a(a^2+a)+1, a^2+a) $$
$$ I = (1, a^2+a) $$
Thus,
$$ \mathbb{Z}[a] / I \cong \mathbb{Z} / (1) \cong 0 $$

To show the ideal is generated by $1$ only note that: $1 = (a^{3} + a^{2} + 1) - a(a^{2} + a) \in I$. Hence $I = (1)$ and the result follows.

Hello Anonymous, welcome to StackExchange! Answer looks good to me. Not much more to say than what JLGL has already provided.
